# How can I use the "Replace" method correctly for a set of characters in Python

Tags: python, replace

```
import re

words = ['Duration12:1', 'Noun', 'Adjective7:8']
result = ([re.sub(r'[0-9]+', r'[\g<0>]', w) for w in words])
```

> ['Duration[12]:[1]', 'Noun', 'Adjective[7]:[8]']

But now after

```
repResult = [x.replace(':[%d]', ':%d') for x in result]
```

I am again getting

> ['Duration[12]:[1]', 'Noun', 'Adjective[7]:[8]']

although I expect the replacement of the characters which should be

> ['Duration[12]:1', 'Noun', 'Adjective[7]:8']

Is this syntax of using the method correct here or am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of `replace` is wrong because you are searching the string literal “%d”. This is not a RegEx.

You can fix your code like this:

```
import re

words = ['Duration12:14254', 'Noun', 'Adjective7:888']
result = [re.sub(r'[0-9]+', r'[\g<0>]', w) for w in words]
repResult = [re.sub(r':\[(\d+)\]', r':\1', w) for w in result]
print(repResult)
```

You get:

```
['Duration[12]:1', 'Noun', 'Adjective[7]:8']
```

With `['Duration12:14254', 'Noun', 'Adjective7:888']`, you get:

```
['Duration[12]:14254', 'Noun', 'Adjective[7]:888']
```

This code can be simplified using a single RegEx:

```
import re

words = ['Duration12:14254', 'Noun', 'Adjective7:888']
result = [re.sub(r'(\d+):(\d+)', r'[\1]:\2', w) for w in words]
```

Comment: for words = ['Duration12:14254', 'Noun', 'Adjective7:888'] it is printing 

Duration[12]:[14254]', 'Noun', 'Adjective[7]:[888]